# How to get a column relationship based on field

Tags: sql, laravel, mariadb

I have a chat table that both a user and admin can chat the table is defined as follow:

id, from_id, to_id, message, is_from_admin.

what I want is, if the is_from_admin is true laravel should use the admin table at sql level for the from. otherwise it should use the user table for from and same applies to the to field. Thanks

Comment: It would have been better if you had provided a more complete explanation of your request

Answer (score 0):

`Laravel` can not solve what you are doing, which is a polymorphic relationship, based on a boolean. Theoretically you could bind the polymorphic class definition to `0` or `1`, but this is a hack at best. Alternatively you could rewrite your table structure to support polymorphic relations.

Instead i would say you achieve something that is working, with what you have. Create two relationships combined with some logic in an accessor. Create a relationship for the admin and for the user.

```
Chat extends Model
{
    public function fromAdmin()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Admin::class, 'from_id')->where('is_from_admin', true);
    }

    public function fromUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'from_id')->where('is_from_admin', false);
    }
}
```

Now create the accessor on the Chat model, using your new relationships.

```
public function getFromAttribute()
{
    return $this->fromAdmin ?? $this->fromUser;
}
```

With this approach, you should be able to access the attribute like this.

```
Chat::find(1)->from; // either a user or admin based on the data.
```

Comment: But from php i can't create two functions with same name, you defined from Admin twice

Comment: that was an typo, meat fromUser :) as you can see how i use the relationship in the getter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the chance, I'd rework the table a bit and name it like so:

```
id, from_user_type, from_user_id, to_user_id, message
```

The pair `from_user_type` and `from_user_id` can be used to creat a custom polymorphic relation ("type" refers to the model/table name, and "id" refers to the id of a row in this table) as seen here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations .

If you also want to send admin-to-admin, you should also add `to_user_type`, `to_user_id` so you can create a polymorphic relationship on the receiving side as well.

The polymorphic relation will look something like this:

```php
class ChatMessage
{
    public function fromUser()
    {
        // This function should automatically infer `from_user_type` and `from_user_id`
        // from this function name.
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class AdminUser
{
    public function chatMessages()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(ChatMessage::class, 'fromUser');
    }
}
```